# How could I make android API calls from my web application?

Tags: android, web-applications

I have 2 applications : one is on my laptop and uses the web browser. The other one is an android application.

I know how to make both communicate using REST webservices. I mainly use it for database query.

But know I need the browser application to make android API calls like Telephony API, Webcam API, etc... and also recieve back informations like SMS in the laptop....

The first thing that came into my mind was using sockets... Is there a better or proper way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) and [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to do HTTP/JSON REST transactions. These handle the raw sockets for you.

Comment: I'm not worrying about HTTP/JSON transactions. I want my web app to make android API calls .... Do not forget android phone does not have an apache server inside so I need some sort of connection between the two software